# How do bookmarklets work regarding cross origin requests - Is cors required?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I know what a bookmarklet is, meaning I know how to create one and that it can access the page that the user is browsing.

What I don't understand is how to send information from that page to my server.

When I make an ajax call to my server from the bookmarklet ( supposing this is possible ), how does it know that the bookmarklet is mine, i.e. not a cross origin request?

Or is this even possible?  Am I required to use cors?

Or can I use the bookmarklet with a plain ajax call?

I simply want to get some information from whatever page/domain the user is on, and send it to my server for processing.

Comment: Bookmarklets are run in the context of the current window. That means they can inject a script into the page from an external source with no problem.

Comment: You can just use JSONP-esque calls in the same way you would inject scripts.

Comment: It would be substantially simpler to set up than CORS for your case, but the latter is also an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does it know that the bookmarklet is mine, i.e. not a cross origin request?

The server doesn't know. The browser doesn't care. The code and all it does is treated as if it was a native part of the page. (You can tell your server side code anything you want to tell it, but that isn't relevant here.)

> Or is this even possible... to get some information from whatever page/domain the user is on, and send it to my server?

If you only need to send data, you can use a regular old POST via a form, or GET via a form or appended script or even an IMG object. To post with a form, create an iframe so the main page's location doesn't change on submission.

If you want to also get data back there is JSONP or AJAX + CORS (specifically the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header). You don't even have to use JSONP in the strictest sense. That is just a standard to pass data. Instead of returning code which makes a single function call with a JSON argument, your server could just as easily return any JavaScript code you wish to execute.

Comment: `If you only need to send data, you can use a regular old POST via a form, or GET via a form or appended script or even an IMG object. To post with a form, create an iframe so the main page's location doesn't change on submission.` | So technically anyone can post to my domain?  Want to make sure I understand cross origin requests.

Comment: Yes, anyone can post to your domain. This in fact opens up one of the most overlooked security issues of most websites called "cross-site request forgery". It is typically prevented (when prevented) by including a security token in authorized forms which are required by the form action handler before submitted data will be accepted.

Comment: why would it be called a forgery, you simply post from any where, there are no tricks involved it seems.

Comment: I didn't event the name, but it applies to a specific security exploit strategy, not to cross site form submissions in general. Google it for details.